# it is the first time I [have driven/ drove] a car

Tags: tense

I hope you guys are having a good time.

I know that The simple past or present perfect can be used for new or recent happenings. (in AmE)
For example, "I lost my key" and "I've lost my key"

On this point, say that you're having a driving lesson and this is your first time driving. Then, would you find this sentence totally fine in that situation? "It's the first time I drove a car."
I learned that we should say "it's the first time I've driven a car." there, but I'm really curious. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the 'present tense' as you are *driving it*. So, why not use the present continuous?

> This **is** the first time *I **am driving** a car*

The event is happening for the very first time and you are expressing it *right there!*

I'd prefer using the other tense if you are talking about the past. Say...

> That *was* the first time (when) I *drove* a car.

Comment: I think it should be  *This is the first time I've driven a car* and *That was the first time I had driven a car*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I just found that the present continuous is not correct there though..